# AngularJS UI Router reload not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angular-ui-router

I have two states in my current apps, which is login and register. If I just open my website towards `localhost:8001`, it is automatically redirect to /login because I've set

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login')
```

But if I open my website towards `localhost:8001/asdf`, it does not redirect to `/login`. It just print not found.

What am I missing?

Here is my full code

**app.module.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['routesApp']);
```

**app.routes.js**

```
var routesApp = angular.module('routesApp', ['ui.router','loginApp']);

routesApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {  

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

**login.routes.js**

```
routesApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        });
});
```

**register.routes.js**

```
routesApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('register', {
            url: '/register',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/register/register.html',           
        });
});
```

**login.controller.js**

```
var loginApp = angular.module('loginApp', ['ngAnimate']);

loginApp.config(function($sceDelegateProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    // Allow same origin resource loads.
    'self'
    ])
});

var loginController = function($scope){
    //test controller
}

loginApp.controller('loginController', loginController);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="assets/less/phinisi.less">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="assets/less/dropdown.less" />
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/angular-payments.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/ui-bootstrap-0.12.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>

    <!-- Login Script -->
    <script src="app/components/login/login.controller.js"></script>    
    <script src="app/components/login/login.routes.js"></script>

    <!-- Register Script --> 
    <script src="app/components/register/register.routes.js"></script>    

    <script src="assets/js/less.js"></script>


  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ui-view></div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: *Not found is a server response. It means, that you should configure server differently. The UI-Router app was on that url in fact not found... not started... not taking over the url handling.*

Comment: So this is quite troublesome. I use html5mode to make urls look natural. But when user type it manually the server won't handle it like if it has the old '#' angular way. What is your suggestion to handle this? should I create a custom 404 page? But I don't seem to find any page like that in my angular project. Is it located on another folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `html5mode` but it appears your server is not set to properly forward requests to your index for Angular to handle.

The server is attempting to find a resource at this location and failing. The reason this did not happen previously, is because the `#` that is present when `html5mode` is disabled causes the browser to recognize that the rest of the URL is not a navigable path. The path prior to the `#` is your `index.html` file, where Angular exists and knows to handle routing based on the proceeding URI path.

Since I'm not sure what server you are running on, I can't provide a specific answer, but this link provides answers for many of the commonly used servers:

- [How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

Please note, you'll need to make the change in your local build too. Here's an example using `grunt` with `grunt-contrib-connect` and `connect-modrewrite`

```
connect: {
    options: {
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 8001,
        middleware: function (connect, options) {

            var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');

            var middlewares = [
              modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]'])
            ];

            options.base.forEach(function (path) {
              middlewares.push(connect.static(path));
            });

            return middlewares;

        }
    }
}
```

What this does is tells the server to route ALL requests back to index.html so that Angular can process the routing.